# Magento - programmatically sell a product

Tags: php, magento, e-commerce, checkout

As the business requirement of the project I'm working on a really complex, we chose not to use the traditional checkout of Magento, and build our own.

All the process is ok and works just fine, however, at the end, I need to **decrease the stock of my sold products**.

What is the code that allow me to do that, **just as if the user went through the normal checkout process?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);
$stock   = $product->getStockItem();
$stock->setQty($stock->getQty() - $ordered_amount);
$stock->save();
```